# CosmosDb Linq Count v3 SDK

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Does anyone know how to (in the new v3 SDK for Azure CosmosDB) from a LINQ IQueryable asynchronously get a Count?

```
        var con = col.Container();
        IQueryable<T> q = con.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(false);
        q = q.Where(d => d._type == type);
        int count = await q.CountAsync()///this is an SDK internal method and does not work
```

Comment: The feature is currently in development and due to be released in the near future

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have learned when CosmosDb says in the near future it could mean in the next 36 months (or longer if they find a new API they want to release ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

version 3.2 of the SDK adds the Async Aggregates feature.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a try with the code below(make some changes according to your actual situation):

```
var con = col.Container();
IQueryable<T> q = con.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(false);
var iterator = q.Where(d => d._type == type).ToFeedIterator();
int totalCount = 0;
while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    var result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
    totalCount += result.Count();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this pull all the documents queried from the server and do the count locally? I want the count to take place on the server.

Comment: Downvoting. Fetching the entire database to make a count is incorrect. It will drive a lot of traffic (thus delay and charges). When database size increases it will also break due to the volume.